# Adding play/pause to a SWF player

Tags: javascript, flash

I have the following .swf player and I wanted to add more controls such as play and pause to the player object:

```
<object classid="player" width="780" height="420" codebase="[longurl]"
    classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
    <param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess" />
    <param name="movie" value="/root/Desktop/test.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="best" />
    <param value="true" name="controller" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="flashvars" 
        value='config={"clip":{"url":"video.flv","autoPlay":false}}' />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
</object>
```

Comment: in the html or in the flash? also what have you tried?

Comment: In html, the video was played by adding the code below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if we could embed Play/Pause options to the controls.

But, we could add a button for "Play/Pause" which on click calls a javascript function to do the Play or Pause for us.

Just add an id="myVideo" to your object tag.

```
<script>
function playPause(){
    if(document.getElementById('myVideo').paused){
        document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
    }
    else
    {document.getElementById('myVideo').pause();
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="playPause()">PLAY/PAUSE</button>

<object id="myVideo" classid="player" width="780" height="420" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess" />
<param name="movie" value="/root/Desktop/test.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="best" />
<param value="true" name="controller" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="devicefont" value="false" />
<param name="salign" value="" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":    
{"url":"video.flv","autoPlay":false}}' />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
</object>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use HTML5 video tags. It makes life much simpler.


[Check this Link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all)

Comment: The code above didn't seem to be working, I wonder what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not working in my case: javascript error 

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'pause'

I guess flash file has to export those functions?