# How to pause Flash videos with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, video, ads

I run ads on my website. My ad network specifically blocks Flash videos but due to the nature of the ad industry currently, not all ads are correctly identified as Flash videos and as such, I sometimes have Flash videos on my website.

I am wondering, is there a way I can pause any Flash videos that may appear on my website? Can I create a JS script that finds any and all Flash videos on my website and automatically pauses them?

Any tips on how to stop these dumb Flash ads?

EDIT: Please note, since the Flash ads are served via an ad network, I don't have any specific SWF file to target -- I need some JavaScript code that scans a page and finds all Flash videos and automatically pauses them.

Comment: Interesting... just brainstorming here, maybe with CSS? #flash {display:none;}  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding play/pause to a SWF player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033190/adding-play-pause-to-a-swf-player)

Comment: @user6245342 Hiding it isn't the goal because it would continue to play in the background and eat user CPU.

Comment: @MateHegedus I really hate it when people mark questions as duplicates without bothering to read first. This question has nothing to do with the one you linked to.